# ArcGIS JavaScript choropleth map with custom data

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online, feature-service

I am using ArcGIS JS API for creating a different type of maps. I am pretty much clear on how do I create point maps using Lat/Long fields. But I don't seem to get a way to create choropleth map like this.

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/visualization-vv-color/index.html

I want to create maps similar to this. It will be limited to the USA but it can be by state or county or zip. From where I am supposed to get geometry information for these regions so that I can use them with my own data and then host a feature layer on ArcGIS online to use in my application? All the examples provided by ArcGIS uses some hosted layer like https://services.arcgis.com/V6ZHFr6zdgNZuVG0/arcgis/rest/services/counties_politics_poverty/FeatureServer/0
but I don't know what do I have to do to host something similar with my own data to create a feature service.

By now I am very familiar with the ArcGIS API, the only thing I don't understand is from where I am supposed to get geometry information for say USA states.

Answer (score 1):

You may find the ArcGIS Dev Labs helpful for this. This one, for example, focuses solely on how to get started with data that isn't a hosted feature service on ArcGIS Online: https://developers.arcgis.com/labs/arcgisonline/import-data/